# File exist on server using C#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check if a file exists on server's disk and I am using following code

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Jaram Images/") + Path.GetFileName(product.Pic_Url2)))
                                            {
                                                WriteError("File  exist!");

                                                //PdfProdCell = new PdfPCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Jaram Images/") + Path.GetFileName(product.Pic_Url2)), true);
                                            }
                                            else
                                                WriteError(Server.MapPath("~/Jaram Images/") + " File doesn't exist!");
```

but I am getting this error:

```
public static void WriteError(string errorMessage)
{
    try
    {
        string path = "~/Jaram PDF/PDFS/" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-mm-yy") + ".txt";
        if (!File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
        {
            File.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)).Close();
        }
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
        {
            w.WriteLine("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            string err = "Error in: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() +
                          ". Error Message:" + errorMessage;
            w.WriteLine(err);
            w.WriteLine("__________________________");
            w.Flush();
            w.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteError(ex.Message);
    }

}

Log Entry : 
05/03/2012 15:50:51
Error in: http://localhost/WebStore/AdminNewAccount.aspx?role=+Administrator. Error Message:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebStore\Jaram Images\ File doesn't exist!
```

---

my log function likes this

Comment: Does the file exist in `Server.MapPath("~/Jaram Images/") + Path.GetFileName(product.Pic_Url2))` ... ?

Comment: first this is not the actually error that you get from exception. Second you map 3 times the same file, why not map it at the first one time. Also the file that not exist is actually a directory as you type it. And finally, debug your code to see whats the real problem

Comment: Not sure what the specific problem is that you're encountering - you've got a lot of code there, and very little error message.  As a random comment, you may want to look into using a real logging library instead of rolling your own.  I suggest [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or (to a lesser degree) [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).  They're super easy to use, super configurable, and are going to be much more fault tolerant than whatever you write on your own (unless you do a *lot* of work on your logging code).

Comment: yes, the file doesn't exist. I want to avoid this error when file doesn't exist that's why I applied If condition.

Comment: @All How can I check if a file exist, so that I can show the image otherwise, skip it ?

Comment: Try `Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Jaram Images/"), Path.GetFileName(product.Pic_Url2)` (and save it in a variable and pass that instead of calling MapPath again)

Comment: @Thomas What If the file doesn't exist ?

Comment: @Thomas I tried it but It didn't work!

Comment: You are already checking if the file exists - if it doesn't it falls through to your else clause which is then raising an error so I don't really understand what your question is. Handle the case where the file exists in your if statement and do nothing in your else clause.

Comment: @KevinMain I added else clause just for testing. Even If I remove it, I get the error. Even If i try if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Jaram Images/")) I get the same error.

Comment: (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Jaram Images/")) will fail as it is a directory not a file from the docs "If path describes a directory, this method returns false"

Comment: @Kevin, I have removed the else part, now how can i check if the file exists in If condition ?

Comment: You are not checking a file you are checking a directory so it will always fail (check your error message) - debug and check what Path.GetFileName(product.Pic_Url2) is returning - my guess it will be null or empty

Comment: @KevinMain I get this error: Error Message:Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JaramWebStore\Jaram Images\201031 and 201059.jpg'.  May be the space in name is problem ? Also 201031 and 201059.jpg doesnt exist thats why I am testing in If

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I understand, you're getting an "error" because you specifically tell the code to write an error even on success.  Try to make your code easier to read.  I set up a simple page to test the problem you're having.  In the HTML I have:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="TestPicture" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Then the following code is in the CodeBehind.  First it checks to make sure if the file exists it sets the URL of the image to the path.  If the file doesn't exist, it simply sets the URL of the image to "".

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serverPath = Server.MapPath("~/Test/") + Path.GetFileName("~/Test/TestImg.jpg");
        string imgUrl = "~/Test/TestImg.jpg";
        if (File.Exists(serverPath))
        {
            TestPicture.ImageUrl = imgUrl;
        }
        else
        {
            TestPicture.ImageUrl = "";
            //TestPicture.Visible = false;
            //TestPicture.ImageUrl = "Picture Not Available.jpg";

            //or do other error checking here
        }
    }
```

For me, when the file exists, the image displays on the web page.  When the file is non-existent, there is no image available.  I commented out some other options that might make sense for you as well.  The "Picture Not Available.jpg" might be a stock image that you could use to show that an image is not available.

If you're still having problems, make sure to put breakpoints in your code and look at what's actually happening.