# Check if file exists in C# is returning false even with Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to check if a specific image exists in a folder. It is in the solution and the code is returning it to me in the watch.

The code is:

```
 using SO = System.IO;


  if (SO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(PathGame)))
            {
                selectJogo.imagemGame = PathGame;
            }
```

But it returns `false`

The watch:

[image: The watch for the variables]

EDIT: SO = System.IO

Comment: `File.Exists()` might be returning false because the ASP.NET user has no permissions to view it, even though the file does exist

Comment: [may be this link could help u.]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427293/file-exist-on-server-using-c-asp-net

Comment: Note that File.Exists never lets you avoid handling all the IOExceptions around file i/o anyway.  The file can be created or destroyed between a call to File.Exists and whatever follows it. You must always include the exception handling in your actual use of the file regardless.

Comment: What is `SO.File`? Never heard of such class. The standard .NET class is `System.IO.File`. Could you show the code of this custom class you are using? Maybe there's a problem with it.

Comment: Sorry. Missed the 'using SO = System.IO;' on top.

Comment: The file exists locally (Server.Map return the path correctly) and it´s in solution.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior. I know the file is there, because in the same code I can open it as a stream and send it back as a response.